# Dynamically setting a storyboard-generated UILabel's attributed string with two different fonts (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel in my storyboard, and I have an @IBOutlet to it in my controller. In my viewDidLoad, I am setting its attributed text with two different font sizes.

```
let str1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "first", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)])
let str2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "second", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)])
str1.appendAttributedString(str2)
myLabel.attributedText = str1
```

Unfortunately, when I run the app, I can see the "firstsecond" string, but all in the same size (`str1`'s 15-point font). Why is `str2`'s 10-point font not being set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `addAttribute(...)` to apply multiple attributes to the same string.

```
let first = "first"
let second = "second"
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: first + second)
string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15), range: NSMakeRange(0, first.characters.count))
string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), range: NSMakeRange(first.characters.count, second.characters.count))
myLabel.attributedText = string
```

Comment: `first.characters.count` and `second.characters.count` wouldn't work for me. I had to use `count(first)` and `count(second)` instead in Xcode 6.4

Comment: Oh oops. I was in Xcode 7.2. The syntax changes. Remember this when Swift 2 is finalized.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't think this is where my issue is. If I check my code in a Playground, it gives me the attributed string I'm looking for, font sizes and all. For some reason, it just doesn't work when I assign it to the attributedText property of the UILabel. Could this have something to do with the defaults in Interface Builder?

Comment: @vinsanity555 keithbhunter's answer worked for me; I tested it in Xcode 6.4. The only change I had to make was changing `first.characters.count` to `count(first)`, but as he pointed out, you'll need to remember this switch when Swift 2 is officially released.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for UILabel's attributedText property states:

> assigning a new value updates the values in the font, textColor, and
>   other style-related properties so that they reflect the style
>   information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

So whatever the style information is at location 0, that's what the label's going to be. That's why you're only seeing str1's 15 point font.